# How do I run another command in a cmd batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this command that i need to run

```
cd /d C:\leads\ssh & C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby192\bin\setrbvars.bat
```

this opens the command prompt

but I need to run this command in the prompt

```
ruby C:\lead\leads.rb
```

which will fire off a script.....but i have no idea what to add to my bat file to do this

i tried the -f flag to tell it to run the command but no go....any ideas to what to do to make this run

```
cd /d C:\leads\ssh & C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\Ruby192\bin\setrbvars.bat -f ruby C:\lead\leads.rb
pause
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier not to open the command prompt but to simply run the command in current window? This would mean a simple change in the command you want to run.

Comment: i need to run this script every 30 minutes so i added it to a bat file that is using windows task scheduler to run...so i need to tell my bat file to run the script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following batch file:

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\leads\ssh 
call C:\Ruby192\bin\setrbvars.bat
ruby C:\lead\leads.rb
```

Comment: are you forgetting the C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Comment: no, cmd.exe will be called automatically when the filename ends in .cmd or .bat.

Comment: exactly what i meant in my comment, simply drop the cmd call :) well done Wimmel :)